# Connect to SQL Server in AngularJS

Tags: sql-server, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and I want to know how to connect to SQL Server, get data from it and show it using AngularJS.

Thaks in advance.

Comment: is a Thak something like a Yak ?

Answer (score 2):

Angular JS is a client side architecture, you can't connect a database directly. What you need is an API on server like web service, MVC, webapi etc, to which you can make calls from your Angular js app.

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs is client side framework based on javascript. There is nothing to do retrieving data from SQL server. It is server side's duty.

You should implement on server side technologies such as .net or php, and give services to client side through web api, rest api etc.